# questions about limits and derivatives

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to solve a set of problems, this one is causing my some troubles. For the first one I tried to use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition but I couldn't solve it, I would appreciate some hints for it.

Let $f:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f'$ is continuous and $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$. Prove or give a counter example for each of the following statements:

1. if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}f(x)=0$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}f'(x)$ exists.
2. if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x) = 0$

Comment: You have been in this site for about 8 months according to your profile. Are you not yet aware that it is impolite to post in the imperative mode, as if *you* were assigning homework? Or that the best steps to take when posting a homework problem is to add what it is you are having trouble with or what you have tried so far?

Comment: Arturo is right.  There is no excuse if you have been here for a long time.  So, what have you tried so far? (Etc...)

Comment: Sorry for being rude, I'm editing the post right now. And I'm avoiding to post something else like "wondering" because last time Arturo used it against me :'(

Comment: The thing [last time](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34944/the-calculation-of-dimu-v-w) wasn't the use of the word "wondering". It was that you posted a formula from a source that said it was (incorrect and) derived from inclusion-exclusion, and you were "wondering" *if* the formula (though incorrect) could be derived from inclusion-exclusion. What I couldn't figure out is why you were wondering if this was the case, given that your source *said* that was the case and explained why it was the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to both is no.
**(1):**  Consider $$f(x)=x\left(2+\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right).$$  As $x\rightarrow 0$ it has to go to zero by the squeeze theorem, as $|\sin (x)|\leq 1$, and is always positive as well.  However, the derivative will have the term $$\frac{-1}{x}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ which behaves badly.

**(2):**

For the second one, consider $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\left(2+\sin(x^2)\right)$$ when $x\rightarrow \infty$.  Certainly $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ by the squeeze theorem, and $f(x)$ is always positive since $|\sin(x)|\leq 1<2$.  Lastly $$f^'(x)=\frac{-2}{x^2}-\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}+2\cos(x),$$ and $\cos(x)$ has no limit as $x\rightarrow \infty$.

Hope that helps,