# Dimension of the sum of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V_1, \ldots, V_n$ be $n$ subspaces of a vector space $V$.

Is there a formula for $\dim(V_1 + \cdots + V_n)$ similar to 
$\dim(V_1 + V_2)=\dim(V_1) + \dim(V_1) - \dim(V_1 \cap V_2)$?

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34944/the-calculation-of-dimu-v-w and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17740/is-there-a-version-of-inclusion-exclusion-for-vector-spaces

Comment: Didn't notice those, thanks for referring.

Comment: As a curiosity: At the moment the answer related to this is the most upvoted in the MO thread [Examples of common false beliefs in mathematics](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/23501#23501)

Comment: A related post on [mathoverflow.se]: [Is there a version of inclusion/exclusion for vector spaces?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/17740)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This example will illustrate the difficulty.

Let $i,j,k$ be the standard basis vectors for 3-dimensional real space. Let $W,X,Y,Z$ be the subspaces spanned by $i,j,k,i+j$, respectively. Then $W+X+Y$ has dimension 3, $W+X+Z$ has dimension 2, but $W,X,Y,Z$ all have dimension 1, and any intersection of two or more has dimension 0. So, no formula using dimensions of the four spaces and their intersections can distinguish between $W+X+Y$ and $W+X+Z$.