# Finding $\dim(A_1 + A_2 +\cdots + A_n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The calculation of $\dim(U + V + W)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34944/the-calculation-of-dimu-v-w)

Given a linear space $V$ and subspaces $A_i \subseteq V$ such that $1\leq i \leq n.$

To find $\dim(A_1 + A_2 +\cdots + A_n)$ it seems we can use inclusion exclusion.  Is there any other way of finding it?

Comment: Do you have any extra assumptions e.g. that you know $dim(A_{i})$ for all $i's$?

Comment: How are you using inclusion-exclusion? The obvious thing is false.

Answer (score 3):

You say that "To find $\dim (A_1+A_2+⋯+A_n)$ it seems we can use inclusion exclusion", so I want to point out that while for $n=2$ the inclusion-exclusion formula 
$$ \dim (A+B) = \dim A +\dim B - \dim A\cap B$$
is true, it fails for $n=3$: in general
$$\dim (A+B+C) \neq \dim A+\dim B + \dim C - \dim(A\cap B) - \dim(B\cap C) - \dim (A \cap C) + \dim(A\cap B \cap C).$$
Look at the example of three distinct lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The problem is that subspaces of a vector space don't form a distributive lattice, in other words $A \cap (B + C) \neq A \cap B + A \cap C$.  Repeatedly using the $n=2$ formula will give you an expresion for $\dim (A+B+C)$, but not just in terms of the terms appearing on the right of the displayed equation above.

Comment: Are there a set of circumstances / restrictions in which it generally holds for n>2?

Comment: I would guess that, for a collection of subspaces $S_1,\ldots,S_n$ every proper subcollection of which is distributive (i.e. intersection distributes over sum), $S_1,\ldots,S_n$ obeys inclusion-exculsion iff it distributive.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you already know about the $A_i$.

For example, you can write down the list of all basis vectors of all $A_i$ and determine the rank by row reduction.